# Is it possible to implement a subroutine that modifies an array declared as non allocatable?

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine

I want to implement a function (or subroutine) in order to remove a number of elements from an array.

```
subroutine delete_elements(array, number_elements)
    type(tcb),dimension(size(array)),intent(in)::array
    type(tcb),dimension(size(array)-number_elements),intent(out)::new_array
    integer::number_elements
    new_array=array(number_elements+1:size)
  end subroutine delete_elements
```

I want to know if it is possible to modify the array called `array` directly without moving by a new array, knowing that I want to declare array as a non allocatable array. Is it possible ?
And is it correct if I implement an array with `size(array)` as a size ?

Comment: Not totally sure I understand what you are asking, but you can't change the memory footprint of a non-allocatable object, end of story.

Comment: So it should imperatively be declared as allocatable ? Is there a predefined function in fortran doing the same work ?

Comment: If you want to delete an element of a 1D allocatable array in Fortran simply `a = [ a( :index -1 ), a( index + 1: ) ]` will do it. But as mentioned in another questions arrays are not good data structures if you want to start deleting and adding elements somewhere in the middle.